# VLC shuts down immediately after startup

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, manjaro

Ever since I started using Manjaro, I've been having this problem with VLC (which I hadn't encountered on Windows) that it shuts down immediately when I start it. The only way I got VLC to work is when open it up from a terminal.

I even tried reinstalling it a couple of times but the problem persists. Here's my log file:

```
﻿-- logger module started --
main: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
lua: Listening on host "*console".
lua: Requested shutdown.
main: playlist is empty
-- logger module stopped --
```

Comment: If you create a keyboard shortcut, https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Keyboard_Shortcuts , identical to the way you'd start it in Terminal, does that work?

Comment: Then it would work perfectly but my problem is that when I try to open a video file nomrally, it doesn't show up. Actually the VLC GUI shows up for 1 second then vanishes

Comment: I  have theexact same problem right now, on raspbian, it worked fine for about a week, not any more though.

Comment: @mal I gave on that version of VLC and I installed it through flatpak. https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.videolan.VLC